# What's wrong with this if elif statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

```
 if [[ (thing1 -eq 0) && (thing -eq 0) && (thing3 -eq 0) && (thing4 -eq 0) ]]; then
      echo "no flags"
 elif [[ (thing1 -eq 1) && (thing -eq 0) && (thing3 -eq 0) && (thing4 -eq 0) ]]; then
      echo "-g flag"
 elif [[ (thing1 -eq 0) && (thing -eq 1) && (thing3 -eq 0) && (thing4 -eq 0) ]]; then
      echo "-p flag"
 fi
```

Any ideas please? Gives me errors and I have no idea why.

Comment: thing1 will never equal zero. If you want to compare value stored in thing1, use "$thing1".

Comment: Please tell us wihch errors you get. This is always important. There is a reason for errors to occur. I guess thing1 is a variable?
I think it should be like if [[ ($thing1 -eq) ...
and same goes to others

Comment: Are you trying to parse flags/options used when running your script? If so, consider using `getopts` instead - http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of square parentheses here, so use:

```
[[ $thing1 -eq 0 && $thing -eq 0 && $thing3 -eq 0 && $thing4 -eq 0 ]];
```

Also probably you meant to use variable instead of constant strings like thing, thing1 etc.

Comment: great, that works, I will mark this as the answer asap.